# Is it possible dial numbers during a call with Sinch?

Tags: java, android, phone-call, sinch

I am developing an App and I am using Sinch.
What I am trying to do is making a Call and add the feature to show a dial and dial numbers during a call. 
I can't find any documentation or reference about that on Sinch.com
Is anybody work with that?

Answer (score 1):

You can send DTMF tones during a call using the `sendDTMF(String keys)` on the call. See more here - https://download.sinch.com/docs/android/latest/reference/index.html?com/sinch/android/rtc/SinchClient.html

Comment: what about receiving DTMF, not sending?